# Subset timeseries (date sequence) into a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a series of dates, here's a simplified version of it:

```
> eventdates
  dr.rank   dr.start     dr.end
1      14 1964-09-30 1964-10-06
2      16 1964-11-01 1964-12-24
```

I also have a time series of dates with values etc. associated with that, here's a much simplified version of the timeseries:

```
ts1964 <- data.frame(DATE = seq(from = as.Date("1964-01-01"), to = as.Date("1964-12-31"), by = "days"),
                     Q = 1:366)
```

What I am trying to do is subset by each date in eventdates, i.e.:

```
> filter(ts1964, ts1964$DATE >= eventdates[1,2] & ts1964$DATE <= eventdates[1,3])
         DATE   Q
1  1964-09-30 274
2  1964-10-01 275
3  1964-10-02 276
4  1964-10-03 277
5  1964-10-04 278
6  1964-10-05 279
7  1964-10-06 280
8  1964-10-07 281
9  1964-10-08 282
10 1964-10-09 283
11 1964-10-10 284
12 1964-10-11 285
13 1964-10-12 286
14 1964-10-13 287
15 1964-10-14 288
16 1964-10-15 289
17 1964-10-16 290
18 1964-10-17 291
19 1964-10-18 292
20 1964-10-19 293
21 1964-10-20 294
22 1964-10-21 295
23 1964-10-22 296
24 1964-10-23 297
25 1964-10-24 298
26 1964-10-25 299
27 1964-10-26 300
28 1964-10-27 301
29 1964-10-28 302
30 1964-10-29 303
31 1964-10-30 304
32 1964-10-31 305
33 1964-11-01 306
>
```

But I need to do this hundreds of times. What I would like to do is have each subset form an element in a list. I would normally be considering to using something like `dlply` in `plyr` but this isn't an option when I'm using `dplyr`. Could anyone advise on how I might achieve this otherwise? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your example be `filter(ts1964, ts1964$DATE >= eventdates[1,1] & ts1964$DATE <= eventdates[1,2])`?

Comment: good catch @Abdou, it should read [1,2] and then [1,3]. I'll amend :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y) filter(ts1964, DATE >= x & DATE <= y), 
                    eventdates$dr.start, eventdates$dr.end)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Just trying to understand how this works. Is it essentially using a form of `apply`? (well, `mapply`...)

Comment: It's somewhat equivalent to `lapply(split(eventdates, seq(nrow(eventdates))), function(x) {
    dplyr::filter(ts1964, DATE >= x$dr.start & DATE <= x$dr.end)
})`.